# RDP Copy&Paste Error: Windows cannot find '%1!ls!'

Tags: rdp, file-transfer

After working for years on mRemoteNG, and copying and pasting from servers I use all the time, I suddenly started getting the following error on a particular Windows 2003 server:

```
Windows cannot find '%1!ls!'
```

Copying and pasting from the exact same server works with regular RDP (mstsc.exe). Everything seems to be set up fine in both, including clipboard and drive sharing.

Reading numerous online forums did not give the right direction, but the solution was fairly simple (see answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was unbelievably simple: enabling Smart Card sharing did the trick and copying&pasting works again.

I am still trying to figure out why—on other almost identical Windows 2003 servers, Smart Card sharing is still disabled and copying and pasting still works.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me using the Remote Desktop Manager from Devolutions. I had to enable the "Smart Card Sharing" under the Local Resources Tab of the Connection's parameters.

Comment: Am using RDM from Devolutions as well and needed to disable Clipboard sharing in `Local resources`. Smart card-related options didn't change a thing and clipboard makes somewhat sense as that has changed over the years in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The other thing you need to be cognizant of is if your RDP program has the "Connect to Console" checked. Then uncheck it.. or add the check to the "Smart Drive" shared resource.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue with a Colleague. While we use mRemoteNG in our environment, he was using only the built in rdp client, mstsc.exe.
We found that for this particular server he had enabled the local C: drive to be shared from the Local Resources -> More button.

In our environment SMBv1 is blocked, and since the server is 2003 (and hence only has SMBv1) there must be some kind of volume check going on via terminal server that results in the error. Once the C: drive was no longer shared, the right-click -> copy function worked again.